# Can custom locale spec live under ~/?

Tags: locale, non-root-user, profile

I understand that one can put custom locale specs under a system-wide directory (e.g. `/usr/share/i18n/locales`), but is there a way to configure one's locale to use a spec that lives under `~/`?

Alternatively, is there a way for a user *who does not have root access* to use a custom locale spec?  (By "custom" I mean one that is not supplied out of a system-wide locale specs repository.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [`locale(1)` man page](http://www.dsm.fordham.edu/cgi-bin/man-cgi.pl?topic=locale&ampsect=1) it can - you'll need to set the `LOCPATH` environment variable to point to the directory of your choosing (at least on some Linux systems). Note, that there are several sources of `locale(1)` man page - I have been able to locate at least two referring to Linux. I suppose you'll need to try to see whether this works on your system.